# Creating center-lines from amorphous-shaped polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, road

I would like to create road-center lines for amorphous-shaped images as in the example. void area is shown with white and solid area is shown with black. So I would like to create a center-line for the white area.

I have polygon version of the image also, but how can we produce center-lines for this image?

I've tried collapse dual lines to center-line command but it did not work.

[image]

---

When I tried to use dual lines, it does not create anything new or it just draws a very short line at the edge of the void area actually. What I want to do to create something similar to this.

[image]

I do not have ArcScan, I used ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Can you share some examples of what you've already tried?

Comment: I would think you'd have to first extract those white cells, then use some raster processing to 'thin' the group down to at minimum a 1-raster wide road. Then you can convert that to polyline using tools within QGIS or ArcGIS...

Comment: What I'd try: extract nodes from the black polygon and use them to compute a Voronoi diagram of the white polygon.

Comment: I do not have Arc Scan, I used Arcmap 10.3. I have tried to done first two advice and I am still working. but more detailed explanations would be really helpful. thank you

Comment: I Think what you want is called Skeletonize, see for example [skimage Skeletonize](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html)